# filepicker the front end cropper

Tags: filepicker.io

> To make it even easier to work with user content, we enable image post-processing. This way, regardless of what type of file a user uploads from the Cloud or their local device, you can be sure it's in exactly the right size. To convert an image, take the filepicker url and append /convert, along with query parameters specifying what you want to change. See the Docs»

filepicker.io shows an example of a cropping tool on their front page. Could that be built into the picker itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We've discussed building it into the upload experience a la iOS, but think that the functionality is best done as a step after the upload. The demo on our front page is done using [JCrop](http://deepliquid.com/content/Jcrop.html), and at some point we'll open-source the demo as a jquery plugin or similar.